# Is this notation correct?

Tags: notation

I am writing a paper and I have an expression something like this:

$$\begin{equation}
    \notag
    x = \text{large_expression} + \begin{cases}
            y & \text{if } a<b \\
            z & \text{if } a=b \\
        \end{cases}
\end{equation}$$

Will this notation be understood just as well as this more common, undoubtly correct way?

$$    x = \begin{cases}
            \text{large_expression} + y & \text{if } a<b \\
            \text{large_expression} + z & \text{if } a=b \\
        \end{cases}$$

Note that splitting up $\text{large_expression}$ and $y$/$z$ will hurt the understanding a lot, as well as break the flow of the paper.

Comment: You could make a compromise and let $x =$ large_expression $+f_{a,b}$ where $f_{a,b}$ is what it needs to be depending on $a$ and $b$

Comment: Can't you do "large_expression + $x$ where $x = y if...z if...$"?

Comment: Ok what @TobiasKildetoft offered is simillar but better than mine. Good job :)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I'm afraid that will hurt the understanding. This is for describing a cryptographic scheme, and placing $\text{large_expression}$ and $x$/$y$ further apart from eachother (by introducing another variable or function) will make it harder to see that some events are mutually exclusive, on which the security of the scheme relies.

Comment: The notation you suggest is probably also fine (at least I don't see any way it can be misunderstood).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than indicator expressions I would suggest the equivalent but somewhat more readable (once you are used to them) [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)
$$ 
    x = \text{large_expression} + [a<b]y + [a=b]z\quad.
$$
But the solution you suggested is also perfectly understandable an unambiguous, so I don't see much wrong in using it. After all the normal use of the case distinction braces is just after "$=$", which is also in the middle of a syntactic construct; I don't see a fundamental difference when using it after "$+$".

Answer (score 0):

You could use indicator functions (see, e.g., http://www.statlect.com/indica1.htm for their usage in probability theory) and write:

large expression + $y*1_{a<b} + z*1_{a=b}$